# Option for IAM user policy with AssociateAddress permission but disallow Re-association of elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I tried creating a policy for IAM user that enables the user to allocate and associate elastic IP.

But the problem is the user is also able to re-associate already existing elastic IP of another instance.
Is there a way to disallow such re-association while creating policy?

Following is the policy I have applied

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "ec2:DisassociateAddress",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:AssociateAddress",
                "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
                "ec2:AllocateAddress"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, however you would have to do some IAM policy manipulation and use tags to allow or deny existing resource access. Probably not the solution you would hope for, but you could tag existing resources with a tag like Name:EIP-Protection, Value=Yes. You can assign the tag to an EC2 instance or EIP.

Then you would attach an IAM policy document to the user/group/role that would Conditionally deny or allow access to specific resources or ones with that tag/value combination.
Check the AWS docs, this link might shed some light on how to achieve your ask. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_tags.html

Or just add Policy to the user's IAM role like so

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Sid": "AllowAllButEC2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "NotAction": [
            "ec2:DisassociateAddress",
            "ec2:TerminateInstance"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {"StringNotEquals": {"aws:RequestedRegion": [
            "us-east-1"
        ]}}
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. But I need something other than tagging instances.

Comment: Understood, that's just the AWS recommended way of using policy to provide conditional access to resources, also one that is used in many enterprise organizations I've touched.

Comment: Updated my answer with some policy statements to achieve your desired results. You can drill down further and only deny specific arns, instance id's etc.

Comment: Thanks again. I did try that previously but it didn't work. I have updated my question with the policy I have tried

Comment: Updated again, if you try that NotAction version it should give all EC2 permissions except those in the Allow block. It seems like you have something that is granting the permission even with explicit deny in place.

Comment: NotAction will allow or deny every action other than the mentioned ones. Sorry but thats not what I need
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notaction.html